# Flickr API で日本で撮影された写真を指定することは可能？

Tags: api

Flickr API で日本で撮影された写真を指定することは可能でしょうか？

**試してみたこと**
・bboxで日本の緯度経度を指定してみたのですが、中国で撮影された写真が混ざることがあります
・多分、日本列島の形が四角形ではないので、緯度経度で指定してしまうと、仮想四角形となるエリア内に外国も含まれてしまうからだと思うのですが

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using Flickr API to search photos by location or language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474427/using-flickr-api-to-search-photos-by-location-or-language)

（１）先ずは、

`flickr.places.find`: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.places.find.html
から、  WOE (Where on Earth) をゲットする。日本のWOEは`23424856`
（２）[https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=ＸＸＸＸ&format=ＸＸＸＸ&tags=ＸＸＸＸ&woeid=23424856](https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=%EF%BC%B8%EF%BC%B8%EF%BC%B8%EF%BC%B8&format=%EF%BC%B8%EF%BC%B8%EF%BC%B8%EF%BC%B8&tags=%EF%BC%B8%EF%BC%B8%EF%BC%B8%EF%BC%B8&woeid=23424856)